# Cypress: capture and log all XHR requests to a file

Tags: cypress

Using Cypress to test a web app, I have tests failing because of an unexpected XHR response from our test backend.

The screenshots and screencasts doesn't help understanding why we get this error message from the webapp. It would be very useful to get the actual XHR requests logs as an artifact.

It seems to be possible to capture some routes using cy.route, but it seems to be more suitable to stub requests.

What is the correct way to capture and write the XHR logs alongside the screenshots and videos ? It would be even better if it would delete the file if everything passes.

Comment: DId you find any solutions?

Comment: Yes but it's quite hard: you have to create a wrapper on your webapp to pass Cypress all the requests. Then, code something on cypress to write the details on a file. It's been a long time and I can't find the code anymore (can't remember if it was working)

Answer (score 0):

To record the network traffic in the same manner like the network tab in devtools, you can utilize the HAR file format (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/). To generate a HAR file during the execution of your Cypress tests you can use the [cypress-har-generator](https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator) plugin.

```js
describe('my tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    // start recording
    cy.recordHar();
  });

  after(() => {
    // save the HAR file
    cy.saveHar({ waitForIdle: true });
  });

  it('does something', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.com');

    // ...
  });
});
```

It will save a HAR that can be used to inspect the network activity, identify the performance issues or troubleshooting bugs. The file can be skimmed using any kind of viewer (e.g. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-76/#HAR).